# How to Splunk search for transaction types that have a median latency above 3 seconds

Tags: splunk, latency, splunk-query, splunk-calculation, splunk-formula

I have a table that shows latency data, now i want to write a query for an alert that will alert when requests (method + uri) have a higher median than 3000ms (3s)

The query i use for that latency table is:

```
index=ms-app  environment=prod AND "*"
| eval uri=replace(mvindex(split('request.uri', "?"), 0), "\/\d+[-+\w]+", "/:n"), methodOverride='request.headers.X-HTTP-Method-Override'
| eval methodOverrideStr = if(isnull(methodOverride) OR methodOverride=="null", "", "(" + methodOverride + ")")
| eval request = 'request.method' + methodOverrideStr + " " + uri + " " + 'response.httpStatusCode'
| stats
min(stats.overallResponseTimeInMilliSeconds) as "Min",
avg(stats.overallResponseTimeInMilliSeconds) as avg_latency,
max(stats.overallResponseTimeInMilliSeconds) as "Max",
median(stats.overallResponseTimeInMilliSeconds) as "Median",
perc95(stats.overallResponseTimeInMilliSeconds) as "95th %",
count(request) as "# req total", count(eval('stats.overallResponseTimeInMilliSeconds' > 3000)) as "#>3s",
count(eval('stats.overallResponseTimeInMilliSeconds' > 5000)) as "#>5s",
count(eval('stats.overallResponseTimeInMilliSeconds' > 10000)) as "#>10s" by request
| eval "Avg" = round(avg_latency, 0)
| table request, "Median"
```

This produces a table displaying the median latencies based on method + uri
For example:

- POST /first-endpoint    1000
- GET /second-endpoint    2000
- DELETE /third-endpoint  1500
- POST /fourth-endpoint   4000
- GET /fifth-endpoint     4500

Now i am trying to create a query that will show only the method +uris that have high median latency above 3s so that i can create an alert, to alert splunk which endpoints have high latency
This is what i tried:

```
index=ms-app  environment=prod AND "*"
| eval uri=replace(mvindex(split('request.uri', "?"), 0), "\/\d+[-+\w]+", "/:n"), methodOverride='request.headers.X-HTTP-Method-Override'
| eval methodOverrideStr = if(isnull(methodOverride) OR methodOverride=="null", "", "(" + methodOverride + ")")
| eval request = 'request.method' + methodOverrideStr + " " + uri + " " + 'response.httpStatusCode'
| stats
median(stats.overallResponseTimeInMilliSeconds) as "Median"
| table request, "Median" > 3000
```

Which should display this:

- POST /fourth-endpoint   4000
- GET /fifth-endpoint     4500

However it just shows the same results as the first query

Comment: If you're going to only `| table` 'Median' and 'request' - you don't need to do all those extra `stats` steps :)

Comment: yea those were for an earlier query, forgot to remove them,  thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `where` command to filter events based on field values.

```
... | where Median > 3000
| table request, Median
```